# passing pointer type to template argument

Tags: c++, templates

I wrote the following code:

```
template <typename T>
void  myname(T* x)
{
    cout<<"x is "<<x;
}
```

and I Invoked:

```
char *p="stackOverflow";
myname(p);
```

It prints `stackOverflow`.

But if I change the template argument from  `(T* x)`  to `(T x)` I get the same result.

So what is the difference between the two template parameters?

```
void  myname (T x)
```

and

```
void myname (T* x)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First case - `T` is deduced to char, so `T*` will be `char*`.
Second case - `T` is deduced to `char*`.
Differences here are in call to such function

For first case should be

```
myname<char>(p);
```

and for second

```
myname<char*>(p);
```

Also, differences will be when you use type `T` in function.

Comment: Excelletanswer. if this is the case, how to pass double pointer like char ** ?

Comment: @Whoami what do you mean? for first case use T**, for second use T, and for third case use T*. Call like `myname(&p)`;

Answer (score 2):

The difference will be visible when you use T in your function

```
char *p="stackOverflow";
myname(p);

template <typename T>
void  myname(T* x)
{
    cout<<"x is "<<x;
    T t;                 // This is char now
}
```

However with this

```
template <typename T>
void  myname(T x)
{
    cout<<"x is "<<x;
    T t;                 // This is char* now
}
```

---

Answer (score 2):

In both cases, the compiler deduces the template argument to generate a function that matches the function argument type `char *`.

In the first case, it instantiates the template with `T = char` giving `void myname<char>(char* x)`.

In the second case, it instantiates it with `T = char*` giving `void myname<char*>(char* x)`.

Also, note that string literals are constants, and you should never point a non-const pointer at one.